# Clickjacking remediation via domain name comparison

Tags: javascript, regex, clickjacking

I'm working on hardening our application to cross frame scripting/clickjacking attacks. Our application is hosted under multiple, different parent sites within an iframe. Each of these parent sites shares the same high level domain name (ex. *.foo.com).  I would like be able to ensure that the parent, framing site is always the same as our application domain.  For example:

Parent sites: apple.foo.com, pear.foo.com, banana.foo.com
Our site: mysite.foo.com

I know I can do something like this via Javascript but I would prefer not to embed our domain name within the code for portability reasons.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var topFrameHostname = "";
try
{
                topFrameHostname = top.location.hostname;
}
catch (err)
{
                topFrameHostname = "";
}
if (self !== top && document.referrer.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?foo\.com(\/|$)/i)) == null && 
                topFrameHostname != self.location.hostname) 
{
                top.location = self.location;
} 
else
{
                var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
                antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
}
</script>
```

So my question is can I use regular expressions to compare the domain name from the `top.location` and `self.location` values?  This way I would be able to ensure it is always only a parent site from the same high level domain framing our application. Looking for a little help with the regular expression coding. Is this approach sound?

Comment: Read about `Same Origin Policy` first. It better to use `X-Frame` headers instead of regex.

Comment: The problem with X-FRAME-OPTION SAMEORIGIN (as I understand it anyhow) it that it only works with the SAME domain name.  So in my example above it would only work if the parent and the child were both mysite.foo.com.  It will not work with multiple sites sharing the same root domain (*.foo.com).

Answer (score 0):

why does anyone think that regex is the one and only magic bullet when talking about matching anything?
How about this:

```
function domain(url){
    if(typeof url === "string") url = new URL(url); //sugar, to handle strings
    return url.hostname.split('.').slice(-2).join('.').toLowerCase();
}

domain(top.location) === domain(self.location)
```

Comment: This is a nice approach.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This code is giving me a Permission Denied error in IE on line: `return url.hostname.split('.').slice(-2).join('.').toLowerCase();`  Any ideas why?

Comment: plz more context. Wich IE-version and what document mode? and what have you passed as url? the location-object? a string?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 and Document Mode 7.  I think I am running into problems with Same-origin Policy when the clickjack script is attempting to access the `top.location`.  Seeing this error in the debugger: **Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://myframe.foo.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://parentsite.foo.com".**

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the reference to `top.location` and use `document.referrer` instead in order avoid the permissions error.  Also, the URL function will not work in IE so I just used string functions to extract and compare the URLs:

```
<style id="antiClickjack">body{display:none !important;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var topFrameHostname = "";
var ref = document.referrer;
var tophld = ref.split("/")[2].split(".").slice(1).join(".");
var selfhld = self.location.hostname.split(".").slice(1).join(".");

try
{
            topFrameHostname = top.location.hostname;
}
catch (err)
{
            topFrameHostname = "";
}
if (self !== top && tophld !== selfhld &&
            topFrameHostname != self.location.hostname)
{
            top.location = self.location;
}
else
{
            var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
            antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
}
</script>
```

This seems to be doing the trick and passing the clickjack.html test page.

Comment: After changing this script I'm seeing some really strange behavior in IE.  Some of the pages will have a blank frame.  But if I hit F12 for Developer Tools I suddenly see the frame.  It's like IE is hiding the frame somehow.  Anyone ever seen this behavior before?